# Tabbed Fragmented applications should have only one activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabactivity

I develop a tabbed application, and since `TabActivity` is deprecated, I'm doing it the `Fragment` way.
Now, is that mean that I should have only 1 `Activity` that will hold the tabs and all the other screens of the application will be `Fragment`'s?

And if the answer is:"Yes, you'll find yourself using just 1 `Activity`", so where is the modularity part of the fragments?? Fragment cannot be reused in other fragments and there is only 1 `Activity`, so what's the point of using fragments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely find yourself doing a single `Activity` which holds a single `Fragment`. This `Fragment` will most likely hold a `TabHost` in order to manage your `TabWidget` which will be your actual tabs.

[Here's the tutorial](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) I found not so long ago when I was creating an Activity with Tabs using the Fragment approach. It's quite well made and self explanatory.